# How can I send/transfer Payment to specific Web App Users using Stripe and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, stripe-payments

I have a scenario where I collect payment on the website and also transfer some amount to the Users.

I came across this Documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_26PHem9AhJZvU623DfE1x4sd');
const transfer = await stripe.transfers.create({
  amount: 400,
  currency: 'usd',
  destination: 'acct_1MTfjCQ9PRzxEwkZ',
  transfer_group: 'ORDER_95',
});
```

but I'm not sure how can I get the destination value for a User?

Any helpful material would be appreciated. I am kind of stuck solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To send funds with Stripe you will want to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) (that Transfers endpoint that you found is part of a Connect process). To send funds with Stripe you will need to register as a platform, create Stripe Accounts for your users, and have them fill out onboarding information including their bank account info. After that, you can transfer funds to their Stripe account which will then be paid out to their bank account.

I'd recommend reading [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts) on choosing your users' account type and then going from there to the specific guide for how to create an onboard that type of Stripe account. Because you are already taking payments on your site and want to make transfers to users from those payments, the [Separate Charges and Transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/separate-charges-and-transfers) guide may be helpful for giving you extra context on how to handle things around creating a transfer from one of the payments that you've taken.

Comment: Do the USERS of my application need to have the Stripe Account? Can I transfer the money directly into their bank account ( other than stripe account )

Comment: Yes, the users of your platform will need a Stripe account. With Stripe, you don't send money directly to their bank account, you transfer money to their Stripe account and that account's balance is later paid out to their bank account. https://stripe.com/docs/connect#route-payments-and-pay-out